# How should I include internship supervisor in my CV?

Tags: cv, internship

I am currently doing an unpaid summer internship at a Lab of particle physics and I want to apply for a paid internship to start in september. As I want to include this internship I'm currently doing in my CV I don't know if I should include my supervisor and if I should, hou detailed should I describe him (position, field of research, etc..). Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Just something simple. I'll assume the professor is at the same university, otherwise just name the university as well.

> Project on *Optimal Underwater Symphonic Expression* under Professor Charlie J. Tuna.

The details of the professor are relatively easy to find for a reader if they are thought necessary.

Comment: thank you ver much, this was usefull! :)

Comment: @ArturSemião You could, in addition, list the supervisor as a reference (but ask them first).